# Can I export plain text data, from Sony Acid?

Tags: music, export, sound-editing

I have a bunch of Sony Acid projects that I want to export as plain text files. I don't mind if they are CSV, XML, or just flat txt files, but I just need a file out that I can pass with my own scripts etc.

The data I am looking to export, are basically just the sample file names, the timings, and possibly some of the properties.

Is this possible in Acid Music Studio? Or are there any third party tools that could help?

Comment: Do you have samples like mp3 files stored on hdd?

Comment: Yeah I have all the samples as separate mp3s, but I don't really care about the samples, I just want the track data such as sample positions, lengths, tempos etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sadly, there is no media position export function in Sony Acid.  Seems it is one of the few (if only) popular DAW that does not do this.  Even Sony's Vegas has this feature, but it has been left out of Acid.  When transferring projects to other DAWs, I've had to painstakingly read the positions and start/end maskings and manually duplicate them in the other DAW.